# React Redux Falcor and RethinkDB boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, rethinkdb, redux, falcor

Anyone who has worked on these stack (React Redux Falcor and RethinkDB boilerplate) has a boilerplate. Please share it.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen a boilerplate project with the exact set up you ask for, however this might help. It's one of the few well set up React Redux boilerplate projects out there. You should however be able to easily add Falcor and RethinkDB by yourself.

https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/